# Core Data predicate returning nothing?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, uitableview

I have a Core Data app, which I have based off the Stanford lectures.

In my top level view controller, I create a 'Trip' which has a one-many relationship with 'Day'. So it looks something like:

```
[Trip tripWithInfo:trip inManagedObjectContext:self.tripDatabase.managedObjectContext];

for (int i=0; i<someNumber; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dayInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[trip copy], TRIP, [NSNumber numberWithInt:i], DAY_NUMBER, nil];
   [Day dayWithDayInfo:dayInfo inManagedObjectContext:self.tripDatabase.managedObjectContext];
}
```

The trip works fine and is displayed properly in my top level view controller. The problem is when I select a trip, which should segue to a daytableviewcontroller (should display the days for that trip), the daytableviewcontroller is blank.

I am doing my fetch request like so:

```
    - (void)setupFetchedResultsController
    {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:DAY];
        request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whichTrip.tripID = %@", self.trip.tripID];    
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:DAY_NUMBER ascending:YES]];

        self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                            managedObjectContext:self.trip.managedObjectContext
                                                                              sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                       cacheName:nil];
    }
```

The tripID's are correct I think (exactly the same when I check using NSLog()), however the screen displays nothing. When I do not use a predicate, everything is displayed so I know it is there. I should also mention that the screen seems to randomly display the correct results for the first or second time adding a Trip object.

What are some reasons that this problem could be a result of?

[image: topViewCOntroller]
[image: First Trip Object]
[image: Second Trip Object]

Comment: Do you actually call `performFetch:` somewhere?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, i am assuming performFetch is the same as calling the above method? if so, then yes. If i remove the predicate, which i understand will display all 'Day' objects then I can see everything. So does that mean @"whichTrip.tripID = %@" is the problem?

Comment: Do you have relationship Days in the Trip? If have, you can access it directly -> trip.days (NSSet)

Comment: It appears I do have days, but how would I use this in the predicate?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer. Turns out I added the wrong predicate in my object category. I had put

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dayNumber = %@", day.dayNumber];
```

But it really should've been

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dayNumber = %@", [Trip tripWithInfo:[dayInfo objectForKey:TRIP] inManagedObjectContext:context]];
```